# Parsing XML tagnames in Java from a URL

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I am trying to retrieve content from xml tagnames from a url, but my int numberOfDetails has a length of 0.  What am I doing wrong?

//Edited Code

```
public String[] dumpTitles(String[] xmlFiles) {


        String[] elementsArray = null;
        try { 
            URL xmlContent = new URL("http://webdev4.matcmadison.edu/mab/AmazonXML/georgeEliot.xml");
            DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(xmlContent.openStream()));


            Toast.makeText(this, "xml file: " + xmlContent, 1000).show();

            NodeList detailsNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Details");
            int numberOfDetails = detailsNodeList.getLength();
            String str = String.format("There are %d Details elements", numberOfDetails);
            Log.println(Log.DEBUG, TAG, str);
            Toast.makeText(this, "number of details: " + str, 1000).show();
            elementsArray = getElementByTagName("ProductName", numberOfDetails, detailsNodeList);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.println(Log.DEBUG, TAG, "XML Parsing failed: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return elementsArray;  

    }

  public String[] getElementByTagName(String detailTagName, int numberOfDetails, NodeList detailsNodeList) throws Exception {
      String[] elementsArray = null;
      ArrayList<String> elementsArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
      Toast.makeText(this, "TEST2", 1000).show();
        for (int k = 0; k < numberOfDetails; k++) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "TEST3", 1000).show();
            Element nDetails = (Element)detailsNodeList.item(k);
            NodeList elementNodeList = ((Document) nDetails).getElementsByTagName(detailTagName);
            Node nodeName = elementNodeList.item(k);
            String nodeString = String.format("%s", nodeName);
            elementsArrayList.add(nodeString);
            elementsArray = elementsArrayList.toArray(elementsArray);
            Log.println(Log.DEBUG, TAG, nodeString);
            Toast.makeText(this, "TEST4", 1000).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, "ELEMENT" + elementsArray[0], 1000).show();

        }

        return elementsArray;
}
```

// Original Code
    String xmlContent = "http://webdev4.matcmadison.edu/mab/AmazonXML/georgeEliot.xml"; 
    Log.println(Log.DEBUG, TAG, "FILE NAME: " + xmlContent);
    String[] elementsArray = null;
    try {
    DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Toast.makeText(this, "xml file: " + xmlContent, 1000).show();
    Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlContent)));
    NodeList detailsNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Details");
    int numberOfDetails = detailsNodeList.getLength();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `StringReader` to read from url. `StringReader` reads string you passed in constructor, it doesn't download file from the web. You can use `URL` class instead:

```
URL xmlContent = new URL("http://webdev4.matcmadison.edu/mab/AmazonXML/georgeEliot.xml");
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(xmlContent.openStream()));
```

Another way:

You can use [constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html#InputSource%28java.lang.String%29) of `InputSource` which takes `String`:

```
String pathToDocument = "http://webdev4.matcmadison.edu/mab/AmazonXML/georgeEliot.xml";
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(pathToDocument));
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Could you please help retrieve the element content into an array